# Update to systemd causes network to fail, have to re-generate and reapply netplan. How do I fix this?

Tags: netplan

I am on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS sometimes when I update I see the last 2 lines in update:

```
Setting up libnetplan0:amd64 (0.106.1-7ubuntu0.22.04.2) ... Setting up
systemd (249.11-0ubuntu3.11) ...
```

and then I lose network. Trying to ping results in "network not initialized".

I then have to run:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

and that restores network. But when I update again in the future it has a good chance of happening again. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please file a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+filebug